Can we update a field due to its value without reading it in firebase?
In firebase, can we update a field due to its value without reading it (without having a local copy)? For example, I have a doc with points field which is equal to 5. I want to add 1 to the points field. Is there a way to update it with updateDoc(doc(db, ... )) without reading first with getDoc?

In SQL you can do UPDATE tablename SET points = points + 1. There may be something similar in Firebase.

You have increment and decrement available for numbers and arrayUnion and arrayRemove for arrays.  All other mutations require reading the document first and computing the final value on your own and writing it back to the document.

For numeric fields, you can use the increment operation for that. In modular JavaScript that's:
import { doc, updateDoc, increment } from "firebase/firestore";

const washingtonRef = doc(db, "cities", "DC");

// Atomically increment the population of the city by 50.
await updateDoc(washingtonRef, {
    population: increment(50)
});

For more examples, see the documentation on Google Cloud: Increment a Firestore document field and Firebase's documentation: Increment a numeric value (that's where I got the above example from).
